# How to print double quotes (") in R

Tags: r

I want to print to the screen double quotes (") in R, but it is not working. Typical regex escape characters are not working:

```
> print('"')
[1] "\""
> print('\"')
[1] "\""
> print('/"')
[1] "/\""
> print('`"')
[1] "`\""
> print('"xml"')
[1] "\"xml\""
> print('\"xml\"')
[1] "\"xml\""
> print('\\"xml\\"')
[1] "\\\"xml\\\""
```

I want it to return:

```
" "xml" "
```

which I will then use downstream.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe `cat('"xml"')` or `cat('" "xml" "')` ?

Comment: "which I will then use downstream." This reads like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/203914). Why do you care how a character is printed if you want to use it for something else?

Comment: that is a good idea, but further downstream I would like to print it to a file, and this will unfortunately not work

Comment: Why do you "print it to a file"? That's not what you usually do in R.

Comment: @Roland off topic, but I use R to do some computation, and then write it to a file, which I then feed into another program that needs to read double quotes. the joy of working with lots of different softwares :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use `cat`:**

```
cat("\" \"xml\" \"")
```

OR

```
cat('" "','xml','" "')
```

Output:

```
" "xml" "
```

**Alternative using `noqoute`:**

```
 noquote(" \" \"xml\" \" ")
```

Output :

```
 " "xml" "
```

**Another option using `dQoute`:**

```
dQuote(" xml ")
```

Output :

```
"“ xml ”"
```

Answer (score 9):

With the help of the `print` parameter `quote`:

```
print("\" \"xml\" \"", quote = FALSE)
> [1] " "xml" "
```

or

```
cat('"')
```